# Strip Tags, remove other characters and mysql_real_escape_string is it enough?

Tags: php, strip-tags

I'm working on a couple of pages to manage data coming from a textarea which the user can use to write some content through a basic editor WYSIWYG. In this textarea I abilitate few tags.
I'm wondering if the following process is going to be enough to protect myself from spam and other hidden dangers related to sql query injection and so on.

My steps

```
function string_db ($value) 
{ 
   $value = (get_magic_quotes_gpc()) ? stripslashes($value) : $value; 
   return mysql_real_escape_string($value); 
} 

$content = string_db(trim($_POST['conten']));
$content = strip_tags($content, '<p><a><b><u><i>'); // The 5 tags allowed
$content = str_replace("&lt;", "", $content);
$content = str_replace("&gt;", "", $content); //In case someone try to type html entities instead of html code

//INSERT DATA IN DB
```

On the page where I display the data previously saved in the db I use:

```
echo html_entity_decode($contentFromDb);
```

Is this enough?
IS there a list of tests to do in order to prove the effectiveness?

Thanks a lot

Comment: You probably shouldn't use strip tags. Apparently it has vulnerabilities. You should instead use something like HtmlPurifier. http://htmlpurifier.org/comparison

Comment: I check about strip tags vulnerabilities and I'm planning to remove all the on(Event) attributes in the tag A. HtmlPurifier is a great solution but it's too heavy

Answer (score 2):

You should use PHP's [PDO](http://php.net/manual/en/book.pdo.php) functionality instead. Using this you create prepared statements, which will help eliminate SQL injection vulnerabilities.

```
$DBH = new PDO("mysql:host=$host;dbname=$dbname", $user, $pass); 
$STH = $DBH->("INSERT INTO table (col1, col2, col3) values (?, ?, ?);");

# assign variables to each place holder, indexed 1-3  
$STH->bindParam(1, $col1var);  
$STH->bindParam(2, $col2var);  
$STH->bindParam(3, $col3var);  

# insert one row  
$col1var = "My first value"  
$col2var = "Value 2";  
$col3var = "Someone's 3rd value";  
$STH->execute();  

# insert another row with different values  
$col1var = "My first value; Query 2"  
$col2var = "Value 2 -- of the second query";  
$col3var = "Someone's 3rd value;#This one has weird characters";  
$STH->execute();
```

In the above example, we connect to the database and set the database handle as `$DBH`. Then we prepare our query and use unnamed placeholders (the `?`s). Next we bind our PHP variables to the unnamed placeholders. Finally, we set our variables and execute the query. This can be repeated with new values, simply by changing the data in the PHP variables.

Comment: Good point about about using pdo and prepared statements. That will help with the SQL injection, but can still be vulnerable to XSS attacks since he is allowing some html through a WYSIWYG and I guess displaying this input.

Comment: I'd also recommend running the input values through one or more of the filter functions (http://php.net/manual/en/ref.filter.php), but I heartily second the use of PDO over the use of the older MySQL libraries.

Comment: Interesting the PDO solution. Just one question the solution that I posted is safe enough for SQL injection? Cause I tried some "attack" and it seems to be safe but I'm not an hacker so I don't know if it's really safe.